# How to Select Dropdown hidden option with Jquery Selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
<select class="form-control" id="prodname" name="pname" >
    <option value="0" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">-- Select Product --</option>
    @{
        foreach(var product in (List<tbleProdcutDetail>)ViewBag.productlist)
        {
            <option value="@product.Id">@product.Product_Name</option>
            <option hidden>@product.Quantity</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

I want to select this option.

```
<option hidden>@product.Quantity</option>
```

I have tried this selector but could not get text.

```
var productunitprice = $("#prodname option").find("hidden").text();
```

Comment: try something like `$("#prodname option:selected").next().text()`

Comment: The selector is `:hidden`. Selector is wrong `$("#prodname").find(":hidden").text()`, remove `option` from the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var text = $("option:selected",this).next().text()` Example below.

```js
$("#prodname").change(function() {
  var text = $("option:selected",this).next().text()
  console.log(text)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="prodname">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option hidden>1.1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option hidden>2.2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But my <select> is in foreach loop

Comment: @SohailAsghar how on earth should we know that, also then your id would be duplicated and an id shall be unique

Comment: var prodUp = $("#prodname option:selected").next().text();
We can get this way.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to adding many unused and hidden options.
You can add the unit price to the relevant option directly using a data attribute for example `data-unit-price`.

```
foreach(var product in (List<tbleProdcutDetail>)ViewBag.productlist)
{
    <option value="@product.Id" data-unit-price="@product.Quantity">@product.Product_Name</option>
}
```

Then simply read it from the selected option. In my humble opinion it is cleaner and doesn't use additional hidden option elements as storage for data belonging to other options.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#prodname").change(function() {
    var productunitprice = $("option:selected", this).data('unitPrice')
    console.log(productunitprice)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="prodname" name="pname">
  <option value="1" data-unit-price="5.25">product 45</option>
  <option value="2" data-unit-price="12.99">product 94</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But My <select> is in foreach loop?

Comment: In your code you show us the select is not inside the foreach loop. If it is you have an issue with duplicate identifiers and you also would be looping through the same product list for all of them -  `foreach(var product in (List<tbleProdcutDetail>)ViewBag.productlist)` - You need to show us that loop if it is an issue but from what you asked in your question you have an answer how to solve it.